# How to get a list as an output from any() Function?

Tags: python, boolean, any

I want to obtain a list of outputs for comparison of a nested list to another list.The nested list is l1 from which I take a single element like say [1,0] and compare it with l2 and if either of the values in element are in l2 it should return True hence the any function ,but i am not able to store the result of any for all elements of l1 an assignment  to a variable results in storing only the last value.I need to store a list of True and false values for each element and l2 comparison.

I've tried converting to list,tuple etc but nothing seems to work 
     a=list(any(map(lambda x: x in l2,i))) or 
     a=tuple(any(map(lambda x: x in l2,i))) 
I keep getting the same error  TypeError:bool object not iterable

```
l1=[[1,0],[2,0],[6,9],[7,1],[5,5]]
l2=[1,2,3,4,0]
x=[]
for i in l1:
 a=any(map(lambda x: x in l2,i))
print(a)
```

I want the variable a to store consecutive Boolean result of the comparison on the nested list item and the set l2
But when I print the data i e print(any(map(lambda x: x in l2,i)))
It provides the correct result for each comparison which is :
True
True
False
True
False

I want the variable a to store the list of values of all these and not just the last value which is False obtained by assignment 
        a=any(map(lambda x: x in l2,i))
I want to increment a variable based on the number of cases being True.

Comment: You want a _list comprehension_, not `any` or `all`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to accomplish this

```py
[any(a in l2 for a in i) for i in l1]
[True, True, False, True, False]
```

`any` and `all` return a single boolean value for the provided iterable, and `bool` does not support iteration, thus it cannot be passed to the `list` function.

```py
list(True)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
l1= [[1,2,3],[3,4]]
l2 = [3,4,5]

for ele in l1:
    boolCheck = False
    for e in ele:
        if e in l2:
           boolCheck = True
    result.append(boolCheck)
return result
```